# How to play video through java script code?

Tags: javascript

I know, I am asking stupid question but your experience will help me to improve my java script knowledge. Now a days, I am trying to learn advance concept in java script. So please help me to develop this small application. I want to play a video on button click event...Would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can building HTML5 video controls with JavaScript

**HTML5**

```
<video>
  <source src="filename.mp4">
  <source src="filename.webm">
  <source src="filename.ogg">
</video>
```

check this [link](http://www.broken-links.com/2009/10/06/building-html5-video-controls-with-javascript/) and [Demo](http://www.broken-links.com/tests/video/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to skin this cat. May I suggest spending some time to get acquainted with JavaFx:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/media/jfxpub-media.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.2/tutorials/javafx-javascript/index.html

I haven't done this myself, but I've been looking for an opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  HTML5 player or a flash player

1. [videojs HTML5 player](http://videojs.com/)
2. [Flowplayer demo](http://flowplayer.org/demos/)
3. and you can use Youtubbe and controll ti using JS [YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)